# How to detect the user comes back to a page rather than starts browsing it?

Tags: vue.js

I've got a grid component that I use in many routes in my app. I'd like to persist its state (ie. paging, search param) and restore it when the user comes back to the grid (ie. from editing a row). On the other hand, when the user starts a new flow (ie. by clicking a link) then the page is set to zero and web service is called with the default param.

How can I recognise the user does come back rather then starts a new flow?

When I was researching the problem I've come across the following solutions.
Unfortunatelly they didn't serve me

1/ using router scroll behaviour

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
to.meta.comeBack = savedPosition !== null;
}
```

It does tell me if the user comes back. Unfortunately the scroll behaviour runs after grid's created and mounted hooks are called. This way I have no place to put my code to restore the state.

2/ using url param

The grid's route would have an optional param. When the param is null then the code would know it's a new flow and set a new one using $router.replace routine. Then the user would go to editing, come back and the code would know they come back because the route param != null. The problem is that calling $router.replace re-creates the component (ie. calling hooks etc.). Additionally the optional param mixes up and confuses vue-router with other optional params in the route.

Answer (score 0):

**HISTORY COMPONENT**

```
// component ...
// can error and only serves the purpose of an idea
data() {
  return {
     history: []
  }
},
watch: {
  fullRoute: function(){
      this.history.push(this.fullRoute);
      this.$emit('visited', this.visited);
  }
},
computed: {
 fullRoute: function(){
    return this.$route.fullPath
 },
 visited: function() {
     return this.history.slice(-1).includes(this.fullRoute)
   }
}
```

**the data way**

[save the information in the browser](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html)

```
// component ...
// can error and only serves the purpose of an idea
computed: {
 gridData: {
   get: function() {
     return JSON.parse(local.storage.gridData) 
   },
   set: function(dataObj){
     local.storage.gridData = JSON.stringify(dataObj)
   }
 }
}
//...
```

[use statemanagement](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

```
// component ...
// can error and only serves the purpose of an idea
computed: {
 gridData: {
   get: function() {
     return this.$store.state.gridData || {} 
   },
   set: function(dataObj){
     this.$store.dispatch("saveGrid", gridData)
   }
 }
}
//...
```

[use globals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object)

```
// component ...
// can error and only serves the purpose of an idea
computed: {
 gridData: {
   get: function() {
     return window.gridData || {} 
   },
   set: function(dataObj){
     window.gridData = dataObj
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: My question is about detecting whether the user comes to the page or rather comes **back** to the page. Let's say we have a few pages: P1, P2, P3, P4. When user navigates from P1 to P2 then P2 starts a new flow. When they go on to P3 and then back to P2 then I'd like to be notified they came back.

Comment: Oh ok - is this more what you are looking for: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive ?

Comment: Keep alive doesn't store the page state when you change the component. That's what happens when I navigate to another page. Anyway it's not what I'm after. I just want to be notified when the user moves back to a page in the browsing history.

Comment: I added some sketch of a history component, that will trigger a @visited event

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Let's say we've got Link, Page1 (it's got your code), Page2. By clicking Link the user navigates to Page1 then navigates to Page2 and then comes back to Page1. That's fine, your code works. However it fails when the user follows Link, Page1, Page2, Link, Page1 because it says the user has come back to P1 which is not true.

Comment: maybe add the check for $route.params before adding the element to history or even delete it from history - was more of a sketch - check https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties - fullPath is maybe not the best to validate - i will try to edit my solution later but right now im busy^^